# Run a second stage as dialog

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

My project has a main GUI (Stage) with some buttons: by right click on a button I would like to run another stage in another package.

Here is the project tree

[image]

newprojectx is the package with the main GUI and

```
togglebuttonDraw.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()){



        }
      }
    });
```

is the method for right mouse click: I would like to run from this button the .fxml from fibonaccipriceretracement package.

togglebuttonDraw is in NewProjectXController class.

Any help really appreciated.

**Edit:** this is the .fxml I would like to run by right click

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fibonaccipriceretracement/FibonacciPriceRetracementDialog.fxml"));
Parent content = (Parent) loader.load();
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(new Scene(content));
stage.show();
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks: I get this exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2021)
 at newprojectx.NewProjectXController$1.handle(NewProjectXController.java:363)
 at newprojectx.NewProjectXController$1.handle(NewProjectXController.java:355)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)

Comment: why do you create a Pane? Shouldn't I create a Stage with Scene, then call Stage.show()?

Comment: hey alberto, I made a spelling error in my example, because I had to actually type it. It should work now. I made a pane because I don't know how your fxml looks like. If you want a new stage with the content of the fxml, check out the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

For small FXML's the solution of Sebastian is good, but if you are experiencing a freeze when you are opening the pop-up, maybe the FXML is too big or you are loading it over the network. In this case the FXMLLoader will block your GUI, so you will need to execute the FXMLLoader in background. You can use a Service that returns the Parent for your Scene, and create the Scene an the stage once the service has been finished.

Here is a full example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    final ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator(-1);
    progress.setVisible(false);

    Button button = new Button("Open fxml");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            final Service<Parent> service = new Service<Parent>() {                 
                @Override
                protected Task<Parent> createTask() {   
                    return new Task<Parent>() {                         
                        @Override
                        protected Parent call() throws Exception {
                            //Out of FX Thread
                            String fxml = "/FxmlTest.fxml";
                            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
                            return root;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            progress.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());
            service.start();
            service.runningProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> value, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {                 
                    if(!newValue){//The service has ended
                        //In the FX Thread
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(service.getValue());
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(button, progress);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I put a progress indicator to show that the service can take a time while loading.

If you want to check where it is in a FX Thread, you just need to use Platform.isFxApplicationThread().

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to run your example but I get error in final Service<Parent> service = new Service<Parent>(), it says type Service does not take parameter

Comment: Are you using javafx.concurrent.Service? I've just edited the answer with the imports I'm using. I recommend you to take a look at the concurerncy javafx 2 tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Comment: In general, I disagree with this solution, loading fxml from a local resource is generally going to be very quick - it is only when you load over a network that performance would be slow enough to warrant using a Task or Service.

Comment: I guess that if the FXML is small there is no problem. But sometimes I've experienced some freezes loading FXML's with a lot of components on it. And when you press the button nothing happen and you see nothing while the popup is loading, and actually the GUI it's freeze. So I guess for that cases this solution isn't a bad solution. And I also modified my answer with the exceptions you propose. Thanks, Cheers.